# Write multiple entries to LDAP in a single bind using JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

Is it possible to add multiple LDAP entries using JNDI in a single shot?

This is what I do to create an entry:

1 Create a BasicAttributes object
2 Add BasicAttribute objects to it
3 Use JNDI's [DirContext bind()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/DirContext.html#bind%28javax.naming.Name,%20java.lang.Object,%20javax.naming.directory.Attributes%29) to bind an entry with these attributes (the BasicAttributes object) to LDAP

My question is, is it possible to do many such operations in a single Step 3?

Comment: Bind doesn't write any entries at all. It is an authentication operation.

Comment: DirContext's bind() does adds entries, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/models/operations.html

Comment: Your language is confusing. In JNDI, `bind()` binds a *name*, with attributes. In LDAP, the 'bind' operation is an authentication operation. Neither of them binds a '`BasicAttributes` object'.

Comment: Well the answer is 'no'.

Answer (score -1):

We have an [example](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/JNDI%20LDAP%20Example%20Add%20with%20Administration%20Account) of what I think you are trying to perform.

Comment: No you don't. That only binds one entry. He is asking about binding multiple entries in a single operation.